# Separating list with nested sublists of different lengths

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider the following list, with sublists of different lengths

```
list = {{{0.8, 0.8, 0.8}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {4, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 2}}, {{1.2, 
     1.2, 1.2}}, {{1.4, 1.4, 1.4}}, {{1.6, 1.6, 1.6}, {4, 2, 2}}};
Map[Length, list]; (*{1, 3, 1, 1, 2}*)
n = Max[%]; (*3*)
```

how can this this list be separated into `n` lists of the length of the original list, where the positions of the elements are maintained, i.e, the output should be

```
e1={{{0.8, 0.8, 0.8}}, {{1, 1, 1}}, {{1.2, 1.2, 1.2}}, {{1.4,1.4,1.4}}, {{1.6, 1.6, 1.6}}}
e2={{}, {{4, 1, 1}}, {}, {}, {{4, 2, 2}}}
e3={{}, {{3, 3, 2}}, {}, {}, {}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Transpose @ PadRight[list, Automatic, {}]
```

> ```
> {{{0.8, 0.8, 0.8}, {1, 1, 1}, {1.2, 1.2, 1.2}, {1.4, 1.4, 1.4}, {1.6, 1.6, 1.6}},
>  {{}, {4, 1, 1}, {}, {}, {4, 2, 2}}, 
>  {{}, {3, 3, 2}, {}, {}, {}}}
> ```

```
Transpose[PadRight[list, Automatic, {}]] /. p : {__?NumericQ} :> {p}
```

> ```
> {{{{0.8, 0.8, 0.8}}, {{1, 1, 1}}, {{1.2, 1.2, 1.2}}, 
>   {{1.4, 1.4, 1.4}}, {{1.6, 1.6, 1.6}}}, 
>  {{}, {{4, 1, 1}}, {}, {}, {{4, 2, 2}}}, 
>  {{}, {{3, 3, 2}}, {}, {}, {}}}
> ```